# shared_ptr as class member corrupts stack?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a shared_ptr in the class like this

```
class App
{
public:
    App(){};
    ~App(){};

private:

    boost::shared_ptr<int> ab;
};
```

when I instanciate one App class in main, the stack gets corrupted?

```
int main(){
   App myApp;
}
```

Does any one know why the error :" Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'myApp' was corrupted." appears, in Visual Studio?

shared_ptr needs no initialization it will be zero anyway or not?
This is quite strange

Comment: The posted code works as expected for me - can you reproduce the error with the posted snippet?

Comment: I doubt the problem is in posted code.

Comment: Could you specify the MSVC version you are using?

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement in `main`.

Comment: `return` is not required in the `main`, by default `main` returns 0.

Answer (score 4):

The code you pasted is fine, shared_ptr has a sensible default ctor and will destruct fine

Comment: Yes, I use the posted code, and they work find. I think Gabriel should give more information besides these codes.

Comment: I resolved the problem! -> VS has problem with the incremental linker... I disabled incremental linking in the linker tab and then, every thing worked fine. The bug looked untrackable, it was no bug, VS did corrupt something when incrementally building the app again